# Magento renaming images

Tags: magento-1.7

I noticed that some of my product images are missing.  After exporting the products, I see that a lot of my images have been renamed with a _1, _1_1, _1_2, etc.  There are actually quite a few in the series.

I use a lot of the images for the same products, so it makes sense that it is making a new image for every product (I guess), but a lot of the images have 0 bytes when I check through my ftp site, hence the reason why some images are not showing up.

Can I go through and delete all of the _* from the file names so that all products that share an image will only use the original image?

If so, what's the best way to do this?  I am new to Magento and learning as I go along.  The company that built my site is a no longer in the picture so I am having to learn everything from scratch and do myself.

I can export the entire database but have never uploaded it and am hesitant to do so for fear of screwing up everything.

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the image resize is creating zero byte files, your website is probably on an underpowered hosting plan. Which in future will be giving you more issues. I'd attack that rather than chasing shadows to destroy Magento's automated image storage. Disk storage space is too cheap to waste time returning to a manual image storage system, which is what you're asking for, even if you don't realize that.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No. Unless there is a very pressing reason for doing this as it would be very time involved I would leave it as is.